# C++ use async with member function

Tags: c++, asynchronous

### I just study and try to use async function in class member function like example in
MS document.

```
using namespace std;
    Class Worker
    {
    private:
        vector<int> work_list;
    public:
        void WorkA(int A, vector<int> B)
        void Work_MP()
    }
    void Worker::Work_MP()
    {
        vector<std::future<void>> v_async;
        v_async.reserve(8);
        for (size_t i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        {   
            v_async.emplace_back(std::async(std::launch::async, WorkA, i, work_list[i]));
        }   
    }
```

---

but, this is C3867 error

1. Why I can't use formal async function with member function?
2. What is wrong in my code?

Comment: `class` should be lowercase, and you didn't attach the error message. Also a bunch of semicolons are missing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of typos in your code, but what I think you are trying to get at is that you have the wrong syntax for a pointer to a member function.  It should be `&class_name::function_name`.  Also, you need to pass `this` as before any other parameters to `emplace_back`, and the last parameter should be `work_list`, not `work_list [i]`.

So, all-in-all, that gives us:

```
v_async.emplace_back(std::async(std::launch::async, &Worker::WorkA, this, i, work_list));
```

Then, [it compiles](https://wandbox.org/permlink/3a1WsgRcV7TNurcy)

Comment: oops...I'm sorry. I wrote it right away without any time to correct the typo because I was in such a hurry. But why I can't call a function directly like in the main when I try to call a member function within another member function?

Comment: You're passing in a function _pointer_, so the syntax is different.  Also, you need to pass `this` so that `std::async` has an instance to call the function (pointer) on.

Comment: ok. now have Compiler Error C2661 instead of C3867. not using 5 Parameters in overloading function.

Comment: My code compiles, as you can see if you follow the link, so please make sure you have transcribed it correctly.  Also, given the typos in your post, I'm not 100% confident that you are compiling the same code that I am, but you need to make sure that the parameters passed to `emplace_back` after `this` exactly match those expected by `WorkA`.

Comment: Your Code  is correctly work.  but I have this syntex error. so when I solve this, write in here. 
No instance of overloaded function "std::async" with matching argument list.
Argument type is (std::launch, void(Class::*)(int i, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int>> work_list), Class*, size_t, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int>>)

Comment: This sounds like a different problem.  Please post a new question, making sure that you post exactly what you are running locally (copy and paste it, don't try to type it in).  There are online compilers where you can test your code before posting which will help with this.  My favourite is: https://wandbox.org/

Comment: Thank you for your kind reply and notice testing site even though I couldn't ask the right question because I haven't asked it many times.

Comment: Posting a [mre] is the main thing.  Then you can just say 'why doesn't this code compile'?